# annotation equivalent of <aop:scoped-proxy>

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am moving from an xml config to annoations. i want to convert a session scoped bean that is

```
<aop:scoped-proxy>
```

can this be done with annotations, and if not, what can i do to still keep that declaration working?

**edit:**
I am interested in doing this in Spring 2.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in the spring context xml, do something like:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.startup.failure" scoped-proxy="interfaces" />
```

Note that you would need to write interfaces for all classes in that package, though.

Answer (score 92):

In Spring 3.0 it can be specified by the `proxyMode` attribute of [`@Scope`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html) annotation:

```
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
```

Comment: proxyMode is not a field of Scope. is this for 3.0?

Comment: @mkoryak yup, it's not there in 2.5: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html but it's in 3.0: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html

Comment: current I found this document https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/javadoc-api/org/springframework/config/java/annotation/aop/ScopedProxy.html#:~:text=Annotation%20Type%20ScopedProxy&text=Marker%20annotation%20identical%20in%20functionality,to%20the%20backing%2C%20scoped%20beans

Answer (score 4):

In Spring 2.5.x

If I do in spring-context.xml something like

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.startup.failure" scoped-proxy="TARGET_CLASS" />
```

So this way I don't need my proxied beans to implement interfaces? (using CGLIB not JDK standard).
Didn't tested this but i think it should work.
Of course you need to have cglib library, you need it with `<aop:scoped-proxy>` anyway.