# Using Session Scope in Spring Beans

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2 for the view and Spring for the business logic. I'm trying to set a session scope to one of my spring beans using annotations(@Scope("session")), but I'm getting this exception:

```
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handleFiles': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private creazione.util.FTPOperations creazione.components.HandleOldFiles.operations; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'ftpOperations': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? 
If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

I know about RequestContextListener. It's in my web.xml. I've also added RequestContextFilter:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>requestContextFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to define the beans that have to be injected as session with aop:scoped-proxy.

```
<bean id="ftpOperations" class="..." scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

Add also the relevant namespace, if it's not present already:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    ...
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        ...
```

Comment: Yeah but I'm using annotations. I have quite a lot of spring beans to write in the applicationContext.xml. Is there an annotation equivalent with <aop:scoped-proxy/> ?

Comment: try to look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503606/annotation-equivalent-of-aopscoped-proxy

Comment: Still doesn't quite work...I've added @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES), I've refactored an interface for every spring bean, but now the AutoWiring doesn't recognize my beans anymore...

Comment: what is the error message? remember that you can specify a Qualifier to help the wiring process such as:         
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("beanName")

Comment: Yes I have used the Qualifier; The exception is:  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [creazione.util.FTPOperations] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=ftpOperations)}

Comment: some stupid questions: creazione.util.FTPOperations is an interface now? Is there a bean implementing it defined as @Component and its package is in context:component-scan?

Comment: FTPOperations it's not an interface (is implementing an interface called Operations) and yes is defined as @Component and yes its package is in component-scan... It's very strange....

Comment: Not quite... I managed to add the session scope to my beans by adding the @Scope(value = "session") annotation and an each interface for every spring bean, but for that to work I deleted the ScopedProxyMode attribute from the Scope annotation - I don't need it for now but I'll need it in the future; Maybe then I'll write the aspect config. in the applicationContext.xml

Comment: If you use the ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES variant you need to change all bean members that are autowired to use the interface instead of the concrete class.

Answer (score 27):

If you are using annotation based configuration, just change in your main config xml this tag:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package"/>
```

to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.package" scoped-proxy="targetClass" />
```

Also it is possible to mark class for working with proxy via annotations:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

This work for me.
More details here: [4.12 Classpath scanning, managed components and writing configurations using Java](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s12.html)

Also if you're create bean via context xml configuration, here is another example for this case:

```
<bean id="somebean" class="com.package.beans" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi this did'nt worked for me. All Three Ways i get the same error could not wire.

Comment: There are many reasoms why it is not autowired - broken scope settings, absent cglib it classpath(in case if you're autowire without interfaces). See your error message for more details.