# struts2-spring-plugin with spring session scope bean

Tags: struts2, spring-web, struts2-spring-plugin

I have web RestClient with struts2 MVC and spring DI and use [struts2-spring-plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/spring-and-struts-2.html#SpringandStruts2-Struts2SpringPlugin) to inject after login Authenticated RestClient bean to struts2 Actions in session scope. If I have in web.xml ContextLoaderListener needed for struts2-spring-plugin

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

There is not session scope (my IDE mark session in red) only prototype and singleton are available:

```
<bean id="restClient" class="com.test.services.RestClient" scope="session">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

If I have in web.xml RequestContextListener session scope appears

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

but this Exception appears [full stacktrace](http://pastebin.com/Xz0wV0rB)

> IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you
>   referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or
>   processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread?

I know that this problem not exist if I switch to spring MVC but can I use spring bean in session scope with struts2 framework or is there any alternative with struts2 ?

Comment: Add both `ContextLoaderListener` and `RequestContextListener`.

Comment: Thanks but this exception appears whith both listeners too.

Comment: Add some code snippets to show how and from where are you calling this bean. And post the whole stacktrace too.

Comment: I have not calling this session bean is injected in struts2 Actions and error appears while application start: Injection of autowired dependencies failed. I have add full stacktrace in question this is the link http://pastebin.com/Xz0wV0rB  If I have change bean scope from session to singleton its not have this exception.

Comment: S2 isn't related. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21286675/1700321 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/7598412/1700321.

Comment: I not think so the problem is that scoped bean must be inside the request thread but struts2-spring-plugin use different thread..

Comment: What? Have you read linked questions? You cannot simple use session scoped beans anywhere you like.

Comment: Yes you are right I have add <aop:scoped-proxy/> to the session bean and Exception is gone. Thanks

Comment: Spring scopes are different than Struts scopes, however if Struts can work without AOP, Spring can't.

Comment: @RomanC I`m not very happy with AOP. Do its have in struts2 analogical to Spring session scope bean?

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/17244036/573032