# How to fix BeanCreateException for a request scope bean used with Spring MVC framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I define a bean with scope request and get an error when i start my application:

> "Cannot resolve reference to bean 'accountDS' while setting bean property 'accountDS'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDS': **Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton**; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found"

I am using this bean from within my controller which is a singleton. Is this why i can't get a request? If so how can i create a scoped proxy? I also have RequestContextListener in my web.xml but it doesn't help.

```
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Can you post your spring context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<bean id="..." class="..." scope="request">
<aop:scoped-proxy />
</bean>
```

Comment: You can also do this with the @Scope annotation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503606/annotation-equivalent-of-aopscoped-proxy