# Spring Web Flow - Handle concurrent access

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have a very basic flow which looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">


<view-state id="gestionParametres" view="gestionParametres.xhtml">

    <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="gestionParametresAction.initialiser()" />
    </on-entry>

    <transition on="annulerParametres">
            <evaluate expression="gestionParametresAction.annulerParametres()"/>
    </transition>

    <transition on="enregistrerParametres">
            <evaluate expression="gestionParametresAction.enregistrerParametres()"/>
    </transition>

    <!-- More transitions -->

</view-state>

<end-state id="back"/>

</flow>
```

Now when I render my page from two different navigators, a change in one page will provoke the same change in the other page. So I want to implement a mechanism that allow my flow to handle concurrent access. How can I achieve that ? I read the spring web flow documentation but I saw nothing about it. May be I am not looking in the right direction...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the annotation `@Scope("session")` on my bean. Obviously the default scope with Spring is `@Scope("singleton")`, so if I understand correctly, the same instance of the bean was used for every flow using the bean. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139571/scope-of-a-spring-controller-and-its-instance-variables) is an other thread that helped me.