# Shared scope in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, session, scope

I have a Spring web app, it has a main controller which instantiates an object such as:

```
@Controller
public class testController {

private Boom boom = new Boom();

}
```

This object would for example have a Get method to display an arraylist of strings for the user to edit and save.

But if there are 2 sessions open, if I edit the list on one and save, then refresh the second session (second browser) it shows on that one. I don't want this to happen. **I'd want the controller to make this object unique for each user viewing the application**

What are my options for scoping this?

Comment: if you want to share the object between different user's session then consider making object scope as `gloabal-session` or `singleton` read more here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm

Comment: Can't you make the Boom a request or session scope bean? Or just create it on fly rather than trying to reuse one instance

Comment: @StanislavL I've done some reading and used @Scope("session") to scope the controller, as the app is small so I'm okay with a new controller for each session. Otherwise scoping the Boom would work fine too! Thank you

Comment: @Travisty , `Controller` must be singleton as a best practice and you should scope `Boom` bean as `Session`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a  best practice , `Controller` Object must be `Singleton` and beans which is being used by them, should have appropriate scope based on their functionality.

In you case as the bean `Boom` is used in a multiple requests across a user-session, hence you should create `Boom` with a scope of `Session`.

Read more about Spring scopes [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_bean_scopes.htm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139571/scope-of-a-spring-controller-and-its-instance-variables).