# spring el not working with @Transactional

Tags: spring, jsf-2, spring-transactions

faces-config.xml

```
- org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>  
<tx:annotation-driven  />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>
```

index.xhtml

```
<h:outputText value="#{authBean.val}"/>
```

AuthBean.java

```
package com.test.ui;

@Component
@Scope("session")
public class AuthBean {

    @Getter @Setter private String val;

    @Transactional  public void test(){}    //works fine if @Transactional is removed
```

Works fine,but when a method is annotated with @Transactional,the below error occurs

```
16:23:13,906 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/jbtst].[Faces Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @14,49 value="#{authBean.val}": The class '$Proxy28' does not have the property 'val'.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
```

Using spring-3.1, hibernate3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helps [annotation equivalent of <aop:scoped-proxy>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503606/annotation-equivalent-of-aopscoped-proxy)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test" scoped-proxy="targetClass" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `@Transactional` Spring creates a proxy that implements the same interface as your class, but your `AuthBean` class doesn't implement an interface.

The easiest way to fix this would be to define an interface with the `val` property and have `AuthBean` implement that interface, the proxy will then also have the val property.

Comment: Thanks, Got some keywords from your answer ,searched again and got solution

Comment: Hi, I am also facing a problem similar to yours. Could you post what the solution was?...