# Is it possible to retrieve a Spring bean with prototype scope without using ApplicationContextAware

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Using Spring 3.1. If I want to retrieve a bean with prototype scope (i.e. I want a different instance of the class each time), is it possible to retrieve the bean without having to use an ApplicationContextaware class?

This is how I do it at present

```
@Component
@Qualifier("MyService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        Blah blah = (Blah)ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getBean("blah");
        blah.setThing("thing");
        blah.doSomething();
    }
}


@Component("blah")
@Scope("prototype")
public class Blah {
    ....
}
```

where ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware.

Is it possible to do this with annotations or simple Spring configuration without having to use an ApplicationContextAware class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring has some fairly sophosticated methods for achieving what you're after...

See the spring documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection

Searching for spring proxy scope on google also threw up some results...

Comment: Yep, think this is what I'm looking for. This SO question shows how to do it with annotations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503606/annotation-equivalent-of-aopscoped-proxy

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a ApplicationContextAware. You just need a BeanFactory (ApplicationContextAware is just a convinient way to get it).

A bean with scope prototype just means that everytime ApplicationContext.getBean is called a new instance of the bean is created. If you try to inject a prototype bean in a singleton, your prototype bean will be injected once (and so is no more a prototype).

There is something called [method injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection) that may help you if you really need it, but it is more complex than simply calling applicationContext.getBean().

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm trying to get away from writing any Spring specific Java be it implementing ApplicationContextAware or using a BeanFactory.