# Spring web app controller field scope

Tags: spring, controller, scope, thread-safety, javabeans

I am experiencing some conceptional difficulty with the scope of some beans referenced in controllers. I have checked a lot of related questions in file and still not sure. Could someone please help me clarify it?

I am numbering the questions or statements as follows to make helper easier to address my problems.

Per my understanding from the the [Spring doc,](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes) in spring web application,

**1)** for any controller, annotated with a `@Controller`, if there is a private field bean, with default bean scope, this field bean will be accessed as the singleton thus susceptible to thread issue;

**2)** If the field bean is marked as `scope=""prototype`, this field bean, within this controller, will still behave like a singleton, thus being not-thread safe.

**3)** To make such a field bean thread safe, we have to make the bean scoped with `request` or `session` right?

The following is a simplified example related to this question:

```
@Controller public Class ControllerA

@Autowired private DefinedBean db;

@RequestMapping("/testPath") public ModelAndView getPathPage(){

  this.db.setTitle("abc");
  this.db.readReportWithTitle();
  ....
  return new ModelAndView();

}
```

So in this example,

**4)** if the DefinedBean is defined through xml configuration with or without explicit scope of `prototype`, this DefinedBean will have synchronization issue, right?

**5)** To ensure this DefinedBean to be thread safe, we have to define it explicitly with `request` or `Session`.

On the other hand,

**6)** if we mark the controller itself with a scope of `prototype` explicitly, will it get rid of the non-thread safe issue with the DefinedBean field? My thought is no, this won't.

**7)** To make the field thread safe, if we are going to control at the controller level, we need to mark the controller with `Scope="Request"` as well, right?

Your comments are welcome and appreciated. If you can comment with "Correct" Or "Incorrect" or elaborate further to those numbered (1~7) statements, Myself and possible those who come later will appreciate more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to leave the controller be a singleton.
[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) is the spring documentation that explains how to bind beans having different scopes.

This is how you would want to define the wired bean:

```xml
<bean id="db" class="DefinedBean" scope="request">
  <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

I have looked up to see how the same can be done with annotations only and I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503606/annotation-equivalent-of-aopscoped-proxy).

Basically, you annotate DefinedBean with :

```
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
```